# Nginx location index trouble

Tags: nginx, web-server

I have troubles with nginx location block.

```
location /myApp/api/account/tutorialPage {
alias /data/www/;   
index tutorial.html;
}
```

if a have strict match - all is fine, a have access to my tutorial.html.
 But i want every link that contains /tutorialPage would lead to tutorial.html.
 So i made next location:

```
location ~ /tutorialPage {
alias /data/www/;   
index tutorial.html;
}
```

It must be something like "if link contains /tutorialPage than go to tutorial.html". But i have 403 error.

> [error] 10148#0: *65346 directory index of "/data/www" is forbidden, client: 194.183.181.44, server: , request: "GET /myApp/api/account/tutorialPage/ HTTP/1.1", host: "my.domain.com", referrer: "https://my.domain.com/"

I have double checked that data/www dir is has chmod 755 (e.g can be read by enyone)

### ----UPD

Example of locations that works

```
    location ~ /tutorialPage\z {
rewrite ^/.* /tutorial redirect;
}

location /tutorial {
alias /data/www;
index tutorial.html;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to internally rewrite the URI:

```
location ~ /tutorialPage {
    rewrite ^ /tutorial.html last;
}
```

The `index` directive determines the default action when encountering a directory, which is not the case here.